# Displaying Friend Requests

Tags: php, facebook

I have been working on making a social-network similar to facebook to use on my home server. However, i have come across a problem with displaying friend requests in the notifications tab of the user profile.

```
<?php
    //Check for notifications script
    $Request = "Requests";
    $Pending = "Pending";
    $nCheck = mysqli_query($Connect,"SELECT * FROM friends WHERE rTo = '$Uname' AND Status = '$Pending'");
    $nNum = mysqli_num_rows($nCheck);
    if($nNum != 0){
        if($nNum === 1){
            $Request = "Request";
        }
        else
        {
            $Request = "Requests";
        }
        echo"<p style=\"font-family: Tahoma; margin-left: 20px;\">You Have <b>$nNum</b> Friend $Request</p><hr />";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($nCheck)){
            $dbFrom = $row['rFrom'];
            $dbId = $row['id'];
            $dbStatus = $row['Status'];
            for($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++){
                echo"<p style=\"font-family: Tahoma; margin-left: 20px;\">$dbFrom wants to be your friend <form action=\"\" method=\"POST\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"A\" value=\"Accept\"></form> <form action=\"\" method=\"POST\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"D\" value=\"Decline\"></form></p>";
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<p style=\"font-family: Tahoma; margin-left: 20px;\">You Have <b>0</b> Friend $Request</p>";
    }
    ?>
```

And then this is the form for the Accept / Decline:

```
<?php
    //Accept/Decline Friend Request Script
    $Accepted = @$_POST['A'];
    $Declined = @$_POST['D'];
    $A = "Accepted";
    $D = "Declined";
    if($Accepted){
        $addFriend = mysqli_query($Connect,"UPDATE friends SET Status = '$A' WHERE rTo = '$Uname' AND rFrom = '$dbFrom'");
        header("Location: Notification.php");
    }
    else if($Declined){
        $addFriend = mysqli_query($Connect,"UPDATE friends SET Status = '$D' WHERE rTo = '$Uname' AND rFrom = '$dbFrom'");
        header("Location: Notification.php");
    }
    ?>
```

The problem is that if more than one notification is present, the last notification will be the one that is accepted or declined. Please help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

- Make use of Prepared Statements. You are not secured against SQL Injections (More information: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)).
- Don't use strings to set a status. Use a numeric value to define a status. That makes it a lot easier to handle.
- Make use of single quotes `'` to avoid having to escape all the double quotes `"` for HTML in your source code. There are alternative ways for string concatenation which are often recommended in coding guidelines.
- Inline CSS formating is deprecated. Use an external CSS stylesheet instead.
- Don't get the entire dataset from your database when you're not in need of the complete dataset. Always only fetch the data you require. Using `*` is not recommended. E.g. you are not in need of `$row['Status']` and `$row['id']` but still save it in a variable for no reason.
- Don't use the `@` operator. Validate your POST-data instead.
- Your for-loop doesn't make any sense. It won't ever have more than one run-through.
- To solve your current major problem, I would assign IDs to friend-requests in order to uniquely identify what friend-request the system is currently dealing with.
- Also, don't use the usernames in queries but the userID. Otherwise, you will face issues in terms of the topic database normalization.
- There is no need to use header() to return to your notifications.php. You can easily proceed with building the notifications.php-view after validating the POST-data and updating your friend-requests accordingly.

Comment: typesafe comparison may not be required, but it´s good to use it anyway. i agree about the rest though, so +1 from me :)

Comment: @luschn: Agreed, also read about the typesafe comparison's better performance. Makes sense to me now, I will fix my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Just so you can find some rationality behind my decisions, i don't worry about mysql-injections because its a home server. Also i retrieved the whole dataset so it would be easier for me to add different aspects to the request, it would keep me from going back and adding it. And lastly, I had the for-loop there for experimentation purposes. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If both code sample exists in one file, that would explain your problem.
You update your friends table:

```
$addFriend = mysqli_query($Connect,"UPDATE friends SET Status = '$A' WHERE rTo = '$Uname' AND rFrom = '$dbFrom'");
```

if the `$dbFrom` value comes from:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($nCheck)){
 $dbFrom = $row['rFrom'];
```

that means you just update the last row.
I would suggest you to post your `$dbForm` too with those 2 forms.

PS: and start using PDO.

Answer (score 0):

also
 try using this

```
$A = "Accepted";
$D = "Declined";
if($Accepted){
    $addFriend = mysqli_query($Connect,"UPDATE friends SET Status = '$A' WHERE  id='$dbId' AND rFrom = '$dbFrom'");
    header("Location: Notification.php");
}
else if($Declined){
    $addFriend = mysqli_query($Connect,"UPDATE friends SET Status = '$D' WHERE  id='$dbId' AND rFrom = '$dbFrom'");
    header("Location: Notification.php");
}
```